# Can an interface be assigned with more than one IPv6 link-local address?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv6

In case if an interface can have more than one IPv6 link-local address. This could be possible if I assign an additional static IPv6 link-local address, resulting in two link-local IPv6 address to an interface.
which address will be used for sending traffic?

I don't want my system to use the default link-local address instead, I want it to use the additional link-local address that I have configured

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and the algorithm for source address selection is detailed in rfc6724.
The question to be asked is why do you want that specific address to be used? Depending on your intention there might be better approaches (e.g. the use of temporary addresses).
To conclude there are two ways of achieving this, please note their precedencd according to the RFC:

- Disabling the IP address you don't wish to be used. On linux this will be something like: ip addr change fe::your-ip dev ifacename preferred_lft 0
- Creating a label for the desired destination prefix. On linux you would use something liken ip addrlabel prefix add.

Comment: I will be using the link-local address as a source in DHCPv6 requesting a global IPv6 address. The server resides in the cloud and the DHCPv6 will be relayed to the server. So I don't want my link-local to be exposed instead I want to use the link-local that I have assigned statistically.